# Thunderbird gives " Not enough disk space " alert, after trying to download more emails ( Win 7, 64 bit )

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, thunderbird, gmail

So, today I have installed Mozilla Thunderbird 24.2.0 on my Windows 7 (64 bit) machine.

It was downloading emails, until it hit an error. An alert showed up saying : 
"There is not enough disk space to download new messages. Try deleting old mail, emptying the Trash folder, and compacting your mail folders, and then try again."

Now, disk space is not a problem, there is enough free space left ( almost 50 % of the drive ).

How to stop the alert and continue downloading ?

Comment: You can check this for appropriate solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/190949/is-it-possible-to-extend-thunderbird-mail-box-size

Comment: Thank you for the link kunna. I am using W7 though and not Linux, is the way of solving this problem still same ?

Answer (score 2):

Thunderbird may have a limit of 4 G Byte maximum folder size. It appears that they have tried to remove the limit, but it may not be 100% successful. This will definitely still have a 4 G Byte limit if the operating system  is 32-bit.

The clue seems to be telling you to delete your old email and compact your mail folders. This would imply that it is a Thunderbird file size issue not a disk space issue.

Comment: I see from another comment you are using W7, but is it 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: It is 64 bit OS.

Comment: However, Thunderbird for Windows is only distributed as a 32-bit executable, so probably the 64-bit OS makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I use Thunderbird in an organization and manage it.

First you create a folder with any name. After this, select your mails, right click and then copy your mails to the created folder. After the copying completes, go to your emails folder and delete the inbox and `inbox.msf` files, and your emails should be downloading then.

Comment: do you do this inside TB, or inside the file browser in the TB profile?

Answer (score 0):

I am using a portable version 24.3.0, the software is saved in a FAT32 USB HDD, the operation system is Windows 8.1. It still has the disk space issue.
Converting the HDD from FAT32 to NTFS can't solve this issue.
I checked the Data/profile/mail, the inbox file size is 3.98GB.
Creating a new folder and moving old mails to the folder can't help, the inbox file size will not change and a new large folder file will be created. 
By compacting the folder, the folder size can shrink, you still can read the mail and also you can start to download mail.
One problem is old mail in the server (Gmail) will be downloaded again,oh my...
So this way doesn't work for a new Thunderbird and a >4GB Gmail, you have to download them and delete them from the server so that other files can be downloaded successfully.
Mason

Comment: Hmmm, it seems that after compacting, Thunderbird only downloaded some old mails and then started to download new mails. It is strange but still solves the problem. Mason